# Eclipse “Class File Editor” Source Not Found while Debugging in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have a project in Java-Hibernate 3.0 , when I debug the project  I end up hammering step over to get out on the "Class File Editor"  Is there anyway to get around this popping up.

It display message like 
Source Not Found
The source attachement does not  contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class.
You can change the source attacemnet by clicking change attached source below:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved this installing  [**Java Decomplier**](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-eclipse). Follow the instructions on the installation of JD-eclispe.